# Overloaded operator trying to take another overloaded operator as parameter

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have classes Pile which represents a card deck, and so contains instances of class Card.
I have overloaded two operators, Pile::operator+= and Pile::operator--.

```
int main()
{
Pile pile1(false); //construct an empty pile/deck
Pile pile2(true);  //construct a full deck with all 52 cards
output(pile1,pile2); //just a little procedure to print both decks

pile1 += --pile2;
output(pile1,pile2);
    ...
```

Operator += takes another Pile as a reference and moves every card from the parameter Pile to *this.
Operator -- takes the topmost card from the pile and returns a Pile containing that one card.

What g++ is giving me is a compile-time error stating

```
error: no match for 'operator+=' in 'pile1 += Pile::operator--()()'
note: candidate is: void Pile::operator+=(Pile&)
```

Below are the overloaded operators:

```
void Pile::operator+=(Pile &other)
{
    Node *n = other.listHead;

        //add each card from other to *this
    while((n = n->getNext()) != NULL)
    {
        this->newCardToList(other.drawCard());
    }
}

Pile Pile::operator--()
{
    Pile pile(false);
    pile.newCardToList(this->drawCard());
    return pile;
}
```

To me it looks like operator+= is trying to take the -- as a parameter.
I tried pile1 += (--pile2); but that didn't change anything.

The thing I want (or need to do here) is to take the topmost card from pile2
and put it to pile1. Could you suggest what is wrong here, as I haven't been able to come up with anything?

Edit:
The += is required to modify both objects here. This is required because the person who gave us this exercise project on our course requires us to do it this way. His design has been really bad though, so I wouldn't be surprised if this solution wasn't even possible.

Comment: Since this design is complete nonsense anyway, just make the fields of pile mutable. Then += can modify the right-hand value while taking it as a const instance as required by the language for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

operator += is not recognized because operator+= correct signature is:

```
Pile operator+=(const Pile &other)
```

If you want to modify `other` inside, you can use

```
Pile& mutable_other = const_cast<Pile&>(other);
```

and

```
Node *n = mutable_other.listHead;

//add each card from other to *this
while((n = n->getNext()) != NULL)
{
    this->newCardToList(other.drawCard());
}
```

Comment: That should be `Pile& mutable_other`, otherwise you're just making a non-const copy (which you could do without the cast but which doesn't help you at all). Unless of course the copy constructor of this class transfers contents...

Answer (score 1):

Your signature and behaviour for `operator+=` are wrong. Arithmetic operators work by value and so should your overloads. Having a mutating `+=` is certainly one of the cases where operator overloading is abused.

By the description, what is happening here is a confusion of object identity and value identity. Instead of moving an object of some type from one storage to another, thinking in terms of values is often easier, better to implement and more natural in a language like C++.

Comment: That is right. This is an exercise project for our C++ course in university and it was suggested that normally this kind of behaviour should be avoided, but that here the operator+= must change both objects.

Comment: @Yappie Your code is making a copy. Also: Good operator overloading is predictable and without surprises. What this is doing is, by my definition, bad operator overloading. Small hacks can not fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `operator--` returns a temporary object which cannot be bound to non-const reference in the parameter of `operator=`:

```
void operator+=(Pile &other) //your code
```

which should be declared as:

```
Pile & operator+=(const Pile &other) //solution
```

and write `return *this` in the implementation of this function.

Comment: But his `operator+=` modifies the argument (as far as I understand). So the issue is deeper than just a forgotten const.

Comment: Yes, the operator+= needs to modify the argument. Added this to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this design doesn't work. May I suggest a superior design:

```
#include <list>
struct Card {};

class Pile
{
    std::list<Card> cards;
public:
    void operator>> (Pile& other)
    {
        other.cards.splice(other.cards.end(), cards);
    }

    Pile operator--(int)
    {
        Pile result;
        result.cards.push_back(cards.back());
        cards.pop_back();
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Pile a, b;
    a-->>b;    //look how elegantly this expresses: take top card from a and append it to b
}
```

Comment: Yes, that'd be better design. Sadly we are to follow the given design :( (that has some.. interesting decisions)